# Is there a way to make a mysql field expire after a time limit

Tags: mysql

I am making a system which requires a temp_pass field in mysql.

The password should only be there for an hour and then get removed.

I have a few options I can think of. I suppose I could check if the password is there on log in and remove it then.

I could of course force them to change their password, and then I could remove it then.

My real question is this. Is there some way in mysql to make a field change to null after 1 hour or a limited time?

I would prefer any answers in mysqli  if such a thing exits

Comment: You could do it entirely with Events. I have 3 event-related links off my profile page. It would be all automated. So, technically, sure.

Comment: No. This is business logic and belongs in your application, not your data persistence layer.

Comment: When you say I can do this with events. Do you mean php events, or mysql events. As I am not sure what events are.

Comment: mysql Events. It is a layer built into the db server. Like I said, i have 3 links off my profile page for Events. Think of them as Scheduled Stored Procs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real solution is to have 2 columns, a `temp_pass` and a `temp_pass_expire`
When you make a temp pass, you would do something like this:

```
UPDATE user
SET temp_pass = 'hashed-temp-pass',
temp_pass_expire = NOW() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR;
```

You can check the expiration on the MySQL side or the PHP side, whichever you're more comfortable with.
If you're comfortable enough on the MySQL side, however, I would recommend doing it on the MySQL side.

Comment: This seems a logical answer. Will leave it open for a bit in case someone gives a better answer, but if they don't I will tick this one. I suppose I could check the expiry time when they try to update their password, and then if expired they can go back and click the reset password button which will give a new tempory password and reset the temp_pass_expire.

Comment: Doing this in the application by comparing two time values is a lot better than having some background task that runs on your database server that deletes things. Those can be quietly disabled or broken which might be a big deal.

Comment: @tadman then perhaps you can't rely on mysql to begin with. They were built in to avoid cron and the need to trigger stuff is some goofy manner or to write some new layer of server agent

Comment: I have to agree with @tadman on this one. Background tasks are harder to troubleshoot than hard, solid code.

Comment: Well server side is not some people's strength so I know it seems scary.

Comment: I believe Pachonk's solution is the way to go. I didn't tick at first in case there was a better solution, but I think I will go with this one.

Comment: @drew not trying to fight at all. Server side is my strength, personally. Simply enough even considering that, this is a far better solution that trying to kick of scheduled events to null the column.

Comment: You don't have to kick them off, they kick themselves off. Plus, it does not require a PHP front end click to make it happen. That said, this whole question is rather bizarre.

Comment: Having an expiring temporary password is bizarre?